# Use of unresolved identifier issue despite of proper declaration syntax in iOS9 swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am developing a program to parse data using JSON in swift. I have written  the following code-

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var arrDict :NSMutableArray=[]
    @IBOutlet weak var jsontblvw: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        jsonparsingfromurl()
    }

    func jsonparsingfromurl()
    {
      let url = NSURL(string: "http://theappguruz.in//Apps/iOS/Temp/json.php")
      let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
      NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { 
        (response, data, error) in
          startParsing(data!)
      }
    }

    func startParsing(data : NSData)
    {
        let dict : NSDictionary!=(try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary
        for var i=0 ; i < (dict.valueForKey("MONDAY") as! NSArray).count ; i++
        {
          arrDict.addObject((dict.valueForKey("MONDAY") as! NSArray) .objectAtIndex(i))
        }    
    }

}
```

when i try to write the line `arrDict.addObject((dict.valueForKey("MONDAY") as! NSArray) .objectAtIndex(i))` it always throws me an error of "use of unresolved identifier arrDict". Why is it showing so despite I have declared the array properly?

Comment: My mistake then - I edited the code (at first just to clean up whitespace, but I did put the method inside the Controller class, as i thought that was a SO mistake)...

Comment: @SwiftArchitect you should revert my edits ^

Comment: Please store (dict.valueForKey("MONDAY") as! NSArray into a local variable ONCE. That kind of inefficient code is nauseating. And learn what fast enumeration is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the function startParsing is declared outside the scope of ViewController, so it won't have access to properties of that class. Did you mean to declare these functions inside the closing curly brace?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple because I was declaring and using the function outside the interface of the class thats why it was not accessing the properties of the particular class.